Running WordPress multisite login from a subdomain
We have a WordPress multisite on a dedicated server with several different domains and subdomains. My devops now said that he wants it to be more secure and that he doesn't want the WP login page to be available on all the pages. What he wants is to have one dedicated subdomain (i.e. login.mydomain.com) where the wordpress login should appear. I have no idea if this is even possible? Has anyone ever done it this way and how would I go about it?
